# Getting error "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: 530 Please login with USER and PASS" while performing ftp

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, ftp-client, ftp-server

I am getting the below given error while performing ftp from ubuntu machine to same machine. I have done the complete setup and able to transfer file using Filezilla. But while doing the same from code it is giving error. Below I have shown the code snippet.

```
String PROTOCOL= "SSL"; //I Have tried with TLS also
FTPSClient ftpsClient = new FTPSClient(PROTOCOL, false);
ftpsClient.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
ftpsClient.connect("192.168.13.5",21);
ftpsClient.login(userName, password);
```

I am getting the error **530 Please login with USER and PASS**. While connecting only. It is not even going to login statement.

Can somebody please point me out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: moreover this is failing at the 3rd line and still the value for the last line is displayed eventhough it never reached that line of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting the error 530 Please login with USER and PASS. While connecting only. It is not even going to login statement.

If it is not even going to the login statement the message might be caused by the server rejecting the `AUTH TLS` command which is used to upgrade the connection to SSL/TLS. This might indicate that the server does not support TLS at all.

> ... able to transfer file using Filezilla.

Are you sure that Filezilla did use FTP with TLS and not plain FTP or SFTP (which is file transfer using SSH, something completely different to FTPS)?

Comment: I am sure I have specifically used FTP only. I am not using SFTP.

Comment: @LoveGupta: if you have used FTP only with FileZilla then you should probably use FTP only within your program and not FTPS (i.e. FTP with TLS).

Comment: Thanks you are right. The issue was I was using FTP with file zilla and FTPS in my code. So that is why I was getting this error. And when I tried to use FTPS with filezilla got the same error there as well. I needed to set up  the FTPS on my local machine as machine was not set up for FTPS it was only set up for FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but when you're saying you're using the server and the Client on one machine, you have to use localhost 127.0.0.1 as IP Adress

Comment: Hey actually the ip address mentioned is the address of my machine and as it is working fine in filezille I am not sure what might be issue with code.

Comment: Even I tried with accessing a friends machine using file zilla and code but the friends machine also I faced the same issue.